# Sweet alert input not focused on jquery ui modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, input, modal-dialog, sweetalert

Please see my jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/fp2vg48z/2/

Here is the code:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $( "#container" ).dialog({
        height: 430,
        width: 620,
        title: 'click hello',
        modal: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Back',
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        ],
        create: function( event, ui ) {

        },
        close: function( event, ui ) {

        }
    });
});

$('.justalert').click(function(){
        swal({
            title: 'hello',
            text:'Please enter name',
            type:'input',
            showCancelButton: true,
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            inputPlaceholder: "E.g john" 
        }, function(inputValue){   
            if (inputValue === false) 
                return false;      
            if (inputValue === "") {     
                swal.showInputError("You need to enter something!");     
                return false;  
            }                               
        swal({title: " success " + inputValue+" added!", type:"success", timer:10000 });
    });
});

$(document).on('click','.hello',function(){
    swal({
        title: 'hello',
        text:'Please enter name',
        type:'input',
        showCancelButton: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        inputPlaceholder: "E.g john" 
    }, function(inputValue){   
        if (inputValue === false) 
            return false;      
        if (inputValue === "") {     
            swal.showInputError("You need to enter something!");     
            return false;  
        }                               
        swal({title: " success " + inputValue+" added!", type:"success", timer:10000 });

    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#container{ padding:20px; background:#ccc;display:none;}
.sweet-overlay{z-index:5000;}
.sweet-alert{z-index:5001;}
```

When sweet alert is triggered while on top of modal, the input doesn't get focus. I can still select the text on top but the focus is not happening. I am not sure whether this is something from the sweet alert.

The input works fine otherwise.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @James!! I have the same problem you mention, did you get any solution?

Comment: Hi @Joseph, sorry decided to do it on it's own and came out from the idea of opening it from the modal. Please let us know anyway if you have any joy on this.

Comment: Hi @James, I solved this problem by adding `modal: false` in JQuery ui modal and adding the code `<div class =" ui-widget-overlay ui-front "style =" z-index: 99; "> </ div>` after the div containing the modal dialog in html using javascript to block content back and so I could simulate the modal window. I found no solution to this problem and this way at least it works.

Answer (score 3):

you can try overwrite bootstrap's enforceFocus function with an empty one

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
```

Comment: wish i knew how this affects bootstrap, but it worked and everything seems fine. thanks!

Comment: Paranic, would you know how to make this work in R? I have a project on github where I ran into this problem with a sweetalert input field

Comment: Why this works and what is the consequence of doing that?